# Need help in URL Rewrite using Tuckey URL Rewrite in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, url, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

Im using struts2 framework and mongoDB database. now i have this URL:

`http://localhost:8084/testURL/pages.jsp?pid=5b2d12a67f7eef1094c6a6de`

I wanna shows this URL

`http://localhost:8084/testURL/pages/5b2d12a67f7eef1094c6a6de` .

I am using tuckey for url rewrite. And following is my urlrewrite.xml. returns 404 not found

```
<urlrewrite>
<rule>
    <from>^/pages.jsp?pid=$1</from>
    <to>/pages/$</to>
</rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you? If not, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: writing as an answer as assumed to be fixing the question and because of the length of the comment</sub>

#### Regex anchors

In regex, [`^` and `$` are reserved character to say `begin` and `end`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). I assume that you use the standard regex matching <sup>(1) in your URL rewriting rules</sup>

#### Regex capturing

You might need to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the parameter and then re-use it in the `to` parameter:

```xml
<urlrewrite>
  <rule>
    <from>^\/pages\.jsp\?pid=(.*)$</from>
    <to>/pages/$1</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

> All the backslashes because you need to escape special characters: the slash `/`, the dot `.` and the question mark `?`
>
> Using the dot in (.*) is pretty overkill, feel free to fine-tune the regex. Example below

If you are sure that your PID is always made of alphanumeric lowercase characters, you can use

```xml
<urlrewrite>
  <rule>
    <from>^\/pages\.jsp\?pid=([a-z0-9]*)$</from>
    <to>/pages/$1</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

You can test your Regex here: https://regex101.com/

#### Note

In Tuckey docs<sup>(1)</sup>, it is mentioned that your situation is used with `<outbound-rule>`. I haven't pushed Tucket that far so I can't tell if using `<rule>` is enough in your scenario:

> ```
> <outbound-rule>
>     <from>^/world.jsp?country=([a-z]+)&amp;city=([a-z]+)$</from>
>     <to>/world/$1/$2</to>
> </outbound-rule>
> ```

---

1: Tuckey documentation: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/